# What does windows 10 do when a user sets "fix scaling for apps" off? Can I detect that setting and warn users to turn that back On?

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-10, autoscaling, dpi

We have a WinForms app targeting 4.5.1 whose DPI Awareness is set to "System".  (Our app is designed to auto-scale everything to your single DPI setting at the time our app is started.)

With Windows 10 1903 and .NET Framework 4.8...
If a user of our app has the scaling set to 150% or more and hits the Advanced Settings and turns "Fix scaling for apps" off, then it SEEMS like Windows 10 starts treating us like we are set DPI Unaware.  Is that what that setting does when turned "off"?  It treats all apps as DPI Unaware and does the bitmap stretching to do the scaling?

(Based on our logging in that mode, WinForms is telling us it is 96 dpi and the CurrentAutoScaleDimensions is showing up as if it is 100%... even though it is 150%... so, it seems like we are being treated as DPI Unaware.)

Is there a way for me to see that setting so that I can warn users to turn that back "On"?

Comment: I'm not sure about that specific setting, but [GetDpiForWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748624(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetDpiForSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748623(v=vs.85).aspx) function may be of interest.

Comment: When you select "system" then you tell the OS that you don't handle DPI changes that occur while your app is running.  Which could happen when you un/dock a laptop, move a window to another monitor, get multiple RDP connections, or the user changes the setting.  In which case DPI virtualization kicks back on and makes text look blurry.  The "fix" they came up with is to present a consistent DPI to the app, but still render text at real DPI metrics so it doesn't look blurry no matter what happened.  Quite a hack btw, no real idea how they pulled that off.